# possible to sort using orderby with property value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

think of a todo list's item has level of urgent, and it can be set by the user. The priority level has index of 1,2,3.. I want to sort the item within ng-repeat.

and I want the high to be the top always, I'm using push.

here is the demo of my app
http://plnkr.co/edit/Ivo4EvtKEZ765waXFFRV?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `orderBy` value is relative to your current object.

So you have to call it : `orderBy : 'priorty.index` instead of `orderBy: 'task.priorty.index'`

Also, be carefull of your HTLM syntax (html double-quotes ending)

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/c1JcmOamMEpzERuVrLzX?p=preview